# iReport exported pdf does not show correct font

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

A PDF generated in iReport using the 'Times New Roman' font appears to be using 'Arial' for its print version.

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: I am using iReport 3.7.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found that, at least for me, I must explicitly set the pdfEncoding attribute, as well as pdfFontName and isPdfEmbedded, on each font tag in the xml, even when using the system encoding, and that "Identity-H" seems to be needed when using unicode.

So:

1. Make sure your ttf font files are available on the classpath
2. <font ... pdfFontName="filename.ttf"
3. isPdfEmbedded="true"
4. pdfEncoding="Identity-H" ... />

Answer (score 1):

have you set the PDF Font Property to Times New Roman as well, or just the Font property?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding your system fonts directory to the classpath?