# Arial font issue in pdf format in jasper report

Tags: pdf, fonts, jasper-reports, ireport

I have a requirement where i need to have font of my reports generated in diffrent formats consistent. When i try to generate the jasper report from ireport4.1.3 the font that i get in pdf format is Helvetica. I have given the font name as Arial Unicode MS(which needs to be consistent in all the formats) and pdf font name as Default. What should I do to make the font in pdf as Arial Unicode MS?

Comment: This should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2586625/1211525

Answer (score 1):

This answers your question better:

[iReport external font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256114/ireport-external-font)

Font extensions should be used. Doing as explained in the link precose supplied should also work. But it's more likely to break; it was deprecated 3 years ago in favor of font extensions.